# Using lua callback to substitute some Arabic characters inserted within tex command

Tags: luatex, callback

I have this example which replaces certain characters with specific ones, the substitution works fine on the entire input stream  but fails on text inserted through a tex command.

Is there a way to make the substitution effective even  on texts inserted through a tex command? @DavidCarlisle suggested using pre-linebreak callback, does anyone know how to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luacolor}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{luacode}
M = {}
addtosubstitutions = function(input,output)
  M[#M + 1] = {}
  M[#M][1] = input
  M[#M][2] = output
end

substitutechars = function(head)
  for i = 1,#M do
    head = string.gsub(head,M[i][1],M[i][2])
  end
  return head
end
\end{luacode}

\def\substitutechars{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",substitutechars,"substitutechars")}}
\def\unsubstitutechars{
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer","substitutechars")}}

\def\addtosubstitutions#1#2{%
  \directlua{addtosubstitutions("#1","#2")}
}

\def\foo{نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار}

\begin{document}

\addtosubstitutions{يمين}{\\textcolor{red}{يمين}}

\substitutechars

نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار

\foo % Substitution fails here

\unsubstitutechars

\end{document}
```

Comment: move `\def\foo{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}` after `\substitutechars`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need `\substitutechars` to replace each occurence of "jump" even inside commands defined before `\substitutechars`.

Comment: that's not how it works. as the name suggests it is a filter as characters are read from the input file line by line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there another callback which can do the expected work?

Comment: not really, you could write foo to a fle and read it back or you could use the pre-linebreak callback but then you have a node list of font-dependent character,ligature, kern nodes so it  is much harder to find words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fun challenge!

#### Problem

The goal is to find a "find string" and replace it with "replacement content" when:

1. The "find string" is a whole ASCII-only word typed in directly in the document
2. The "find string" is in the middle of an ASCII-only word typed directly in the document
3. The "find string" is the result of another command expanding
4. The "find string" is in an `\hbox`
5. The "find string" is Unicode (non-ASCII) text
6. **The "find string" is in the middle of a word written in a complex (Arabic) script**
7. There are multiple pairs of "find strings" and "replacement contents"
8. We should be able to replace the "find string" multiple times in 1 paragraph
9. Do all of this only when inside a `substitutions` environment
10. Be able to do all of these at the same time

#### Solution

*(requires a LaTeX kernel no older than November 2022)*

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\makeatletter
\newbox\find@box
\newbox\replace@box

\begin{luacode*}
local function make_tex_function(name, func)
    local index = luatexbase.new_luafunction(name)
    lua.get_functions_table()[index] = func
    token.set_lua(name, index, "global")
end

local replacements = {}
local function add_substitution(find, replace)
    local find = node.copy_list(tex.getbox("find@box").head)
    local replace = node.copy_list(tex.getbox("replace@box").head)
    replacements[find] = replace
end
make_tex_function("add@substitution", add_substitution)

local function next_glyph(head)
    for n in node.traverse_glyph(head) do
        return n
    end
end

-- local function debug_print(str, char)
--     print(str, char and char.char and unicode.utf8.char(char.char) or "", char)
-- end
local function debug_print() end

local function prev_glyph(head)
    while head do
        if head.id == node.id("glyph") then
            return head
        end
        head = head.prev
    end
end

local enabled = false
local function do_substitutions(head)
    if not enabled then
        return head
    end

    local function traverse(n, find, replace, status)
        if status then
            find = next_glyph(status[2].next)
            local start = status[1]
            if find then
                if n and n.char == find.char then
                    debug_print("CONTINUE", n)
                    status = {start, find}
                else
                    debug_print("FAIL", n)
                    status = nil
                end
            else
                debug_print("END", n)
                replace = node.copy_list(replace)
                start.prev.next = replace
                if n then
                    node.slide(replace).next = prev_glyph(n.prev).next
                end
                status = nil
            end
        elseif n then
            if n.char == find.char then
                debug_print("START", n)
                status = {n, find}
            else
                debug_print("SKIP", n)
            end
        end

        return status
    end

    for find, replace in pairs(replacements) do
        debug_print("")
        for n in node.traverse_glyph(find) do
            debug_print("FIND", n)
        end

        local status, prev_n
        for n in node.traverse_glyph(head) do
            status = traverse(n, next_glyph(find), replace, status)
            prev_n = n
        end
        traverse(prev_n.next, find, replace, status)
    end

    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "pre_linebreak_filter",
    do_substitutions,
    "substitutions"
)
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "hpack_filter",
    do_substitutions,
    "substitutions"
)
luatexbase.declare_callback_rule(
    "pre_linebreak_filter",
    "substitutions", "before", "Babel.pre_otfload_v"
)
luatexbase.declare_callback_rule(
    "hpack_filter",
    "substitutions", "before", "Babel.pre_otfload_h"
)

make_tex_function("substitutions", function() enabled = true end)
make_tex_function("endsubstitutions", function() enabled = false end)
\end{luacode*}

\AddToHook{env/substitutions/before}{\par}
\AddToHook{env/substitutions/end}{\par}

\def\addtosubstitutions#1#2{%
    \setbox\find@box=\hpack{#1}%
    \setbox\replace@box=\hpack{#2}%
    \add@substitution%
}
\makeatother

\addtosubstitutions{words}{\textcolor{red}{words}}
\addtosubstitutions{es}{ES}
\addtosubstitutions{يمين}{\textcolor{blue}{يمين}}

\def\testwords{test words test words}
\def\foo{نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار}

\begin{document}
test words test words

\testwords

.. يمين xx

نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار

\foo

\hbox{\testwords}

\hbox{\foo}

\bigskip

\begin{substitutions}
test words test words

\testwords

.. يمين xx

نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار

\foo

\hbox{\testwords}

\hbox{\foo}
\end{substitutions}

\bigskip

test words test words

\testwords

.. يمين xx

نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار

\foo

\hbox{\testwords}

\hbox{\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

#### Explanation

We hook both the `pre_linebreak_filter` and `hpack_filter` callbacks *before* Babel/HarfBuzz/luaotfload. Inside the callbacks, we traverse through each character in the current paragraph/box. When we find the start of a "find string", we mark its position. If we find all characters in the "find string", then we splice in the "replacement content" where we found the "find string". We repeat this for each "find string" and paragraph/box, then we return the results to TeX.

Comment: To run your callback before HarfBuzz and luaotfload you should normally use the `pre_shaping_filter` callback. Sadly that would execute after babel at the moment, but I would expect that babel also moves into `pre_shaping_filter` soon.

Comment: Thanks for this greate answer, there remains only a small problem is that the word "يمين" in `xx يمين xx`  appear incorrectly

Comment: @SalimBou The word also looks wrong even when the callbacks are inactivated, so this is not caused by my code. I've changed the `xx` to `..` which seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: This give correct result 
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
xx يمين xx
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

If you define strings outside of `\substitutechars` ... `\unsubstitutechars`, you need to do the substitutions somewhere else. You could adjust your `substitutechars()` function so that it also can directly output a (substituted) string. So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luacolor}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{luacode}
M = {}
addtosubstitutions = function(input,output)
  M[#M + 1] = {}
  M[#M][1] = input
  M[#M][2] = output
end

substitutechars = function(head, print)
  print = print or false
  for i = 1,#M do
    head = string.gsub(head,M[i][1],M[i][2])
  end
  if print then
    tex.print(head)
  end
  return head
end
\end{luacode}

\def\substitutechars{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",substitutechars,"substitutechars")}}
\def\unsubstitutechars{
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer","substitutechars")}}

\def\addtosubstitutions#1#2{%
  \directlua{addtosubstitutions("#1","#2")}
}

\def\presubstitutechars#1{%
    \directlua{substitutechars("#1", true)}
}

\def\foo{\presubstitutechars{نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار}}

\begin{document}

\addtosubstitutions{يمين}{\\textcolor{red}{يمين}}

\substitutechars

نص طويل جدا من اليمين إلى اليسار

\foo 

\unsubstitutechars

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know whether this can be a solution in your concrete use case, though.

Comment: Thanks, foo command is just an example, between `\substitutechars` and `\unsubstitutechars`  there can be any commands defined  by  packages or  other files and inserted with `\input` cmd, your answer redefines those commands and this is difficult in my case.